# Need to build a generic query method using LINQ expressions

Tags: .net, linq, mongodb, norm

I'm new and this is probably very trivial but I have the following method which works fine, using LINQ for MongoDB:

```
public T Single<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression) where T : class, new()
{
    T retval = default(T);
    using (var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
    {
        retval = db.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable()
                    .Where(whereExpression).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

But I would like to add a "Select" to it (for projection) using a parameter as well, something that might look like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
public T SingleWithSelect<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> selectExpression) where T : class, new()
{
    T retval = default(T);
    using (var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
    {
        retval = db.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable()
                    .Where(whereExpression)
                    .Select(selectExpression)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

In the hopes that it'll return something similar to the following:

```
var results = db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities").AsQueryable()
.Where(i => i.Id == someId)
.Select(y => new { y.SomeEntity }).SingleOrDefault();
```

**Essentially I just need to know how to pass the SELECT parameter into the return function** - surprisingly hard to find the solution online when so unfamiliar with LINQ.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another generic type to represent the result of the `Select` call.

```
public TResult SingleWithSelect<T, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression,
    Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selectExpression)
    where T : class, new()
{
    TResult retval = default(TResult);
    using (var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
    {
        retval = db.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable()
                    .Where(whereExpression)
                    .Select(selectExpression)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks Tim! When calling the method using the following I'm getting an error message that I'm trying to implicitly convert Anonymous type to "SomeEntity", do you know how I could remedy that as well? Method call: var result = SingleWithSelect<Entity, SomeEntity>(x => x.Id == id, y => new { y.SomeEntity });

Comment: What do you want to return - an anonymous type like `new { SomeEntity = y.SomeEntity }`, or a `SomeEntity`? The `<Entity, SomeEntity>` says you want to return a `SomeEntity`. If you want to return an anonymous type, call `var result = SingleWithSelect(x => x.Id ... etc`.

Comment: I do want to return SomeEntity, I'm just having problems with the syntax (learning LINQ as I go with this)...

Comment: You probably want: `var result = SingleWithSelect<Entity, SomeEntity>(x => x.Id == id, y => y.SomeEntity);`. I'd still expect the `<...>` to be redundant - the compiler can normally figure this part out for itself.

Comment: One thing... db.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable() -> load all collection from mongodb... I think it is not good.

Comment: `AsQueryable` returns an `IQueryable` and not `IEnumerable`? If it's `IQueryable` then it can look at `whereExpression` and `selectExpression`, and return only what's needed.

Comment: Even if the Where clause is for one specific document ID?  db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities").AsQueryable()
.Where(i => i.Id == someId)